# Anxiety and panic attack relieves

Tags: stress, anxiety-disorders

What are the best advices on how to get rid of anxiety and panic attacks? 
It seems like there are so many advices out there that is hard to know which ones are good and which ones are bad. Any suggestions or personal opinions that anyone wants to share?

Comment: Anxiety and panic attacks are a very important problem. Can you add information to your question, such as what you have found when reading about it? This will help you get a more helpful answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have suffered from health anxiety for the last couple of years and let me share some of the things I find helpful.

1. **Stay hydrated**: Drinking loads of water instantly relieves the tightness in your throat and definitely helps alleviate anxiety. If you think you're about to have a panic attack start drinking till your stomach is full and think about the movement of water inside you. This will help you alleviate some of the anxiety.
2. **Take Deep Breaths**: When you get anxious, flight and fight hormones are released into your bloodstream that causes muscle tightness and increased metabolism, elevated heartbeat rate etc. You must start taking deep controlled breaths as soon as you feel anxious. Also by counting backwards from 10 to 1 as you breathe it will help your mind achieve relaxation more quickly
3. **Hypnosis & Meditation**: This is the long term solution to attack the anxiety itself. There are youtubers like Michael Sealey and Jason Stephenson who have wonderful meditation/hypnosis video guides that will help you learn how to control your anxiety and have a more positive outlook. Don't try to meditate when you're having a panic attack as this may irritate you further. Make it a routine to meditate on a daily basis for at least 40-50 mins. While it may not cure your anxiety it will definitely help you and motivate you to practice more meditation and ease your anxiety.

Remember if your anxiety has a psychological source such as some kind of pain or worry then it may be useful to address those issues first. Ask yourself questions like why am I anxious? Is there a specific reason? Identify the reason and act accordingly. If you have a generalized anxiety disorder then meditation on a daily basis should rid you of anxiety once and for all.

Comment: Thank you Weezy, that is very helpful. one thing I would add to your list is that acupuncture has helped me to cope with it more than massages. The people at the acupuncture place had been pretty helpful. I'm pretty lucky to have them close to where I live.

Comment: Yes any kind of massage releases muscle tension. Physiotherapy is very beneficial too.

Answer (score 0):

For all those people that are suffering for the same cause as me, I would like to recommend them to start practicing yoga, it has been so beneficial for me. I didn't think it was going to help me but it did, I was so desperate about getting a solution that I gave it a try even though some friends were laughing at me for practicing it. It takes about 3 weeks of every day doing it. If you are doing it, make sure you are doing the postures that you need to do for anxiety, stress, insomnia, etc. I was doing other kind of postures and then it didn't help me, but a yoga teacher taught me the right ones and I have been feeling so much better. It has helped me even more than acupuncture and massages, since they are only temporary fixes.

You can do whatever you want to do to improve your life but this is what worked for me and I was suffering from this for at least 5 years, and now finally I'm seeing an exit from this everlasting problem, I just felt I had to share this because it feels terrible and I don't wish this to anybody.